# How do I generate a graph in mysql and php based on my sql statement result?

Tags: php, mysql, graph

I have a form with 3 steps on one page. User will enter their input into each of the step one at a time and at the end of the form, it will generate a MYSQL Select Statement based on user input and generate the results in an array for the rows.

```html
$sql = "SELECT `$columns1`,`$columns` FROM `$input`";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
while($record = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
echo $record[0]; //results are being generated through the array.
echo $record[1];
```

I would like to create a column chart based on the results of the select statement. How do I go about doing it. Please do help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one of many libraries, for example [JPGraph](http://jpgraph.net/).

You can find all information (how to use it etc.) on the site.

You might need to transform your data to structure that is useable in JPGraph. (so for example put your data in array into JPGraph objects - see JPGraphs manuals).

This is quick example base on [this](http://jpgraph.net/download/manuals/chunkhtml/ch15s02.html) and [this](http://jpgraph.net/doc/howto10.php): (I still recommend you to read some manuals - without them, this example might be useless!)

```
// Create graph instance
$graph = new Graph(200, 500);

// Some data
$data = array();

// Put your data returned by the SQL query here (5 and 8 are just examples)
$data[0] = 5;
$data[1] = 8;

// Create two bar plots
$plot = new BarPlot($data);
$plot->SetFillColor('orange');

// Create the accumulated bar plot
$gbplot = new AccBarPlot(array($plot)); // Array as parameter because you can combine plots

// Add the accumulated plot to the graph
$graph->Add($gbplot);

// Redner the graph
$graph->Stroke();
```

Comment: Would you be able to guide me with the documentation and how to transform my data to structure that is usable in JPGraphs?

Comment: Edited my answer, added some example. The example is based on the links given so if something does not work for you, check those two links (you should read them anyway!).